# Unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for ('http://localhost:8100/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope')

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I'm trying to set up Firebase Cloud Messaging for a Ionic Angular app.  I'm having issues with my service worker file and I think it's because it's not a http url, according to documentation but I'm not sure how to change that if it is the issue.

I've read the firebase docs but they don't tell how to resolve this issue.

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-messaging.js');
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import {initializeApp} from "firebase/app";
import {getMessaging, onBackgroundMessage} from "firebase/messaging/sw";
firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

The error actually appears in the messaging service I set up to grab a token:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireMessaging } from '@angular/fire/compat/messaging';
import { getMessaging, getToken } from '@angular/fire/messaging';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessagingService {

  constructor(private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging) { }

  async saveDeviceToken () {
    console.log('test')
    const VAPID_KEY = 'key'
    const messaging = getMessaging();
    console.log('messag', messaging);
    await getToken(messaging, {vapidKey: VAPID_KEY})
    .then((currentToken) => {
      if (currentToken) {
        console.log('token', currentToken)
      } else {
        // Show permission request UI
        console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
        // ...
      }
    }).catch((error) =>{
      console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', error);
    })
  }
}
```

[image]

Even though it's appearing in the messaging service, the error leads me to believe it's an issue with my service worker file.  It's in the src/ folder.

```
"firebase": "^9.18.0",
"firebase-tools": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^15.2.2",
"@angular/core": "^15.2.2",
"@angular/fire": "^7.5.0",
```

service worker:

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.0/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({

  });

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

Comment: Can you share your service worker file or your repo so I can try to reproduce the issue on my end?

Comment: added service worker. @tejaz

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Create Firebase-messaging-sw.js where you want
firebase.js
 
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "firebase/messaging";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
};


const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);

export const getToken1 = () => {

    console.log('Requesting permission...');
    if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
        navigator.serviceWorker
            .register(`fullpath-to-/firebase-messaging-sw.js`)
            .then((registration) => {
                Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
                    if (permission === 'granted') {
                        return getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: "your vapid", serviceWorkerRegistration: registration }).then((currentToken) => {
                            if (currentToken) {
                                console.log('current token for client: ', currentToken);

                                // Track the token -> client mapping, by sending to backend server
                                // show on the UI that permission is secured
                            } else {
                                console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');

                                // shows on the UI that permission is required 
                            }
                        }).catch((err) => {
                            console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
                            // catch error while creating client token
                        })
                    }
                })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Service Worker registration failed:', error);
            });

          }
       


    }
```